# Create polygons with fixed size along lines or another polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, vector-grid, polygon-creation

My task is to create layouts for the grey polygon with a rectangle covering multiple parts for the map extend. I then have to calculate the area of they grey polygon within each rectangle. My idea was to automatically create those rectangles along the polygon (or the lines surrounding it) to then calcute the area with expressions in the map layout and use the atlas function to somewhat automate the process.

This is what the project looks like:
[image]

and this is what I somwwhat want to achieve (with a tool if possible):
[image]

I already tried to solve this with the creation of a grid. However the issue I have with grids is that it cannot rotate and therefore not cover the biggest area possible. Sometimes there are only very small bits in the grid, which we cannot use for our plans.

Comment: You could try splitting the line at a typical length and then create oriented BBs?

Comment: What do you mean with BBs?

Comment: Bounding box(es). Sorry.